# USB3 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter that Supports ALTQ (for pfSense)

Tags: usb, ethernet, network-adapter, firewall, pfsense

Does there exist a USB3 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter that supports [ALTQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALTQ)?

I need ALTQ to facilitate traffic shaping in [pfSense](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/trafficshaper/limitations.html). Unnecessary  details are [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1736519/).

Comment: Please post your requirements here and not a link to SU.

Comment: I did; my only requirement is a USB network adapter that supports [ALTQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALTQ). @Irsu85

Comment: [Netgate Forum Topic 174392](https://forum.netgate.com/topic/174392/usb-ethernet-adapters-that-support-altq-for-pfsense).